# How can I select an option in the chosen.js multiple dropdown with the tab key?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Okay,

I've tried many different things, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the tab key to select the selected option after typing in a search. The enter key works just fine.

I would show what I've tried, but I honestly don't know where to start.

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">

</head>
<body>
<select id="chosen_example" style="width: 200px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">A English Test A</option>
    <option value="1">B German Test B</option>
    <option value="1">C Greek Test C</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chosen_control = $('#chosen_example');
        chosen_control.chosen().keydown(function (e, obj) {
            //it's not getting in here
            console.log('key pressed');
            if (e.which == 9) {
                console.log('tab key pressed');
                //not sure what to do at this point
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried `.chosen().bind(...)`. I've tried `$('#chosen_example').bind(...)`, and a few other things

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhpudzk/1/) that goes along with it.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, or if you need more information, please comment.

**Edit - Solution**

Based on the answers received, the one from Wondercricket led me in the right direction.

By changing the core js file `choosen.jquery.js` I added under `case 9` the following:

```
if (this.results_showing) {
    this.result_select(evt);
}
this.mouse_on_container = false;
break;
```

I added this to both `Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker`, and `AbstractChosen.prototype.keyup_checker`

Comment: Just a guess, but could you use `chosen_control.focusout()` to denote that you've left the focus of the element? I could not test effectively with the jsfiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an interesting thing, as it works for single-select chosen, but it does not work for multi-select chosen.

I was able to get the options to be selected through the tab key with a multi-select, but it required a very small change to `chosen.js` script itself.

After diving into the `chosen.js` file on my local machine, I saw that there is already written functionality  to handle `keydown` functions, per the following:

```
Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker = function (evt) {
        var stroke, _ref1;
        stroke = (_ref1 = evt.which) != null ? _ref1 : evt.keyCode;
        this.search_field_scale();
        if (stroke !== 8 && this.pending_backstroke) {
            this.clear_backstroke();
        }
        switch (stroke) {
            case 8:
                this.backstroke_length = this.search_field.val().length;
                break;
            case 9:
                if (this.results_showing && !this.is_multiple) {
                   this.result_select(evt);
                }
                this.mouse_on_container = false;
                break;
            case 13:
                if (this.results_showing) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
                break;
            case 32:
                if (this.disable_search) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
                break;
            case 38:
                evt.preventDefault();
                this.keyup_arrow();
                break;
            case 40:
                evt.preventDefault();
                this.keydown_arrow();
                break;
        }
    };
```

Being the tab key is 9, there is already functionality written to handle it; however there written logic that prevents you from doing what you desire.

If you wish to be able to select an option with the tab key while using a multi-select, removed the `!this.is_multiple` condition within the `if` statement.

```
case 9:
    if (this.results_showing) {
           this.result_select(evt);
     }
     this.mouse_on_container = false;
     break;
```

Comment: I will give this a test when I can and let you know!

Comment: This didn't work, but... I was able to take your suggestion and apply the proper fix in code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer & Demo

There is no easy way to do this, but **I made it work**, I've updated your [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhpudzk/6/) to demonstrate the effect.

### HTML

```
<select id="chosen_example" style="width: 200px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">A English Test A</option>
    <option value="1">B German Test B</option>
    <option value="1">C Greek Test C</option>
</select>
```

Same as your initial markup :)

```
##JavaScript##

var selector = "#chosen_example";
var chosen_control = $(selector);
chosen_control.chosen();
var chosen_element = $(selector + "_chosen");
var chosen_input = chosen_element.find("input");
chosen_input.keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var chosen_option = chosen_element.find("div > ul > li");
        var chosen_index = chosen_option.attr( "data-option-array-index" );
        var index = parseInt( chosen_index ) + 1;
        var chosen_control_option = chosen_control.find("option:nth-child(" + index + ")");
        chosen_control_option.prop( "selected" , true );
        chosen_control.trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
});
```

Here is where the magic happens.

### Explanation

#### Variables

- **selector** : Your controller's selector (preferably an id, haven't tested with anything else)
- **chosen_control** : `JQuery object` containing your select.
- **chosen_element** : `JQuery object` containing the plugin's container `div`.
- **chosen_input** : `JQuery object` containing the plugin's `input`. (Where you actually type)
- **chosen_option** : `JQuery object` containing the current option showing in the plugin's container `div`.
- **chosen_index** : `string` containing the index of said option according to `data-option-array-index`. Keep in mind this index starts at 0 and option's index start at 1.
- **index** : The option's index, equivalent of the chosen index + 1.
- **chosen_control_option** : The actual option in your select element with said index.

#### Development

So this is how I did it, as I said, it's not easy/pretty, but it works:

- First, we get your `select` or, the `chosen_control`
- Then, we execute the plugin and get the container `div`, or `chosen_element`
- Then we get the `chosen_input`, and bind a keydown `event` on it.
- The `event` will detect if tab was pressed and it will do a series of dirty calculations to select the option the tab should show, and it will select it.
- We execute the trigger command for the chosen element to refresh itself.

### Note

I just figured out the code doesn't work if there is more than one option that starts with the same letter, it'll just select the first one, I'll fix it, but not now, it's new years here!

See you, bye :)

Comment: This works, but if you go to tab on the last item, it sits there.

Comment: I actually never revised it because I thought you got your answer from the other dude hahaha, unfortunatly I'm unable to code right now, hopefully by tomorrow I'll have your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existing answers, I put this together to avoid modifying the Chosen source code:

```
// Initialise Chosen
$select.chosen(/* ... */);

// Handle Tab correctly in a multi-select input
$select.next().find('.chosen-search-input').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Tab') {
        let $input = $(this);

        // If the search results list is open
        if ($input.closest('.chosen-container').hasClass('chosen-with-drop')) {
            // Cancel Tab
            event.preventDefault();

            // Send Enter instead
            let replacementEvent = $.Event('keyup');
            replacementEvent.which = 13;
            $input.trigger(replacementEvent);
        }
    }
});
```

However, I didn't use it because the dropdown opens as soon as the field is focused, so the user could accidentally select something when moving around the form with the keyboard.